# Escaping Javascript call before passing onto next function

Tags: javascript

I have a block of HTML I'm passing on, but in that block, I need to make a Javascript call to insert the proper string using an I18n library.

```
$('<div class="modal-dialog"> \
    <div class="modal-content"> \
      <div class="modal-body"> \
        I18n.t("product.loading")<br> \
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>')
  .appendTo($(document.body))
```

I don't know how to make escape that I18n.t call. Right now, the text "I18n.t("product.loading")" is what shows up, when instead I expected that Javascript call to get back a translated version of the string, like "Loading" (if it was English profile). How can I make it so that that Javascript gets escaped or somehow run?

Comment: `.appendTo(document.body)` will work in every browser and saves you a jQuery call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use string addition as in:

```
'<div class="modal-body">' + I18n.t("product.loading") + '<br>' + ...
```

As it appears you've discovered, you can't insert javascript right into the middle of a string definition and expect it to be evaluated.  It won't because it will just be part of the string.  So, you turn it all into a javascript expression that is one string plus the return result from a function call plus another string.